# How Activity Leaked even in default template?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I was developing an app when I suddenly noted that my Activity and all its Bitmap was leaking. I tried to find any strong reference but I couldn't. Then I started to all from the starting and I'm noting that the default template is even leaking. I couldn't understand why. Here is the screenshot.
[image: This is the Main Activity]

[image: This is the default Layout]

[image: This is the Memory Usage]
Here in the memory usage every time I rotated the memory usage increased and every memory drop you see is when I force GC to happen. It never returned to the baseline it had in the starting.
[image: Memory Analyzer]
I know this is not MAT but I had this only at the current time. It showed me 4 leaked activities just there even after I did GC. Why is it happening though. Can anything be done about it.

Comment: I just think it's not running a GC yet so the dead objects are hanging around, waiting for their time to come.  Keep rotating maybe.... 20 times and see if you get an OutOfMemoryException or a GC.

Comment: Well after 7 rotations GC cleans up memory. It goes upto 2.3 MB and then fall back to 1.7 MB. But if this is the base activity then how are we supposed to ensure that mya Activity performs well coz my application is displaying Images Grid View using recycling View and after 7 rotation if it persists then its a problem. My application gets 4 activities alive after 9 rotations and it all lags then.

Comment: @ShikharMathur I noticed the same weird behavior. I'm really confused, when I rotate the template activity theirs count is increased till 25, then I trigger the GC and theirs count is decreased only till 3, no 1. Apparently I don't understand how the GC works on Android. Did you find any explanations about it?

Comment: Well I went through it all again. Thing is Android framework stores it all up to so much not coz it's leaking but coz it wants to minimize the GC trigger coz it's expensive. It would be very expensive to trigger GC events on every screen rotation specially if the user rotates it continuously